# Why can't use Void as the return type for main method

Tags: java, void, main-method

So I wanted to test `Void` type then I wrote this simple program :

```
package ehsan;

public class NumTest {
    public static Void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        return null; /* The compiler forced me to do so. I just can't realize what is the point in returning in Void type!? */
    }
}
```

So now when I want to compile, the compiler complains :

```
main method must return a value of type void
```

Why can't the compiler see that I'm returning nothing and am using `Void`?

Comment: `Void` and `void` are not the same.

Comment: Because the standard defines the signature of the main method to be `public static void main(String... args)`. Autoboxing/unboxing has nothing to do with method-signatures. You can't auto-box a signature.

Comment: Void is not a wrapper for void

Comment: Yup, Java has some messy corners. This is one of them. Get over it and move on. (Nice question by the way though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `void` (lowercase `v`) not `Void` object. `Void` object is not going to get autoboxing like e.g. `int`/`Integer`, see [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) for a list of autoboxing objects.

`Void` is not a wrapper for `void`, it is just an object that has a very similar name so it can be used in places where you need to specify a return type (like e.g. `Callable<T>`), it is just for documentation purposes and to workaround some generic classes return types.

Second use case is in reflection (when you want to check the return value of a `void` function, you will get `Void.TYPE`).

Correct line is:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: So the only use of `Void` is in specifying generic types? ( Sorry for my newbish questions :)

Comment: Usually, there are some other use cases related to reflection, as it is written in `Void` docs: *The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.*

Answer (score 2):

[Void](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) is a class type, so compiler expects you to return a value for it. You should use`void` with lower case letter.

The cause of your error:

> main method must return a value of type void

is due to the rule that main method should always return `void` - which is a java keyword not a class type.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `void` instead of `Void`

Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Typo error.

It is `void` not `Void`

It is happened that Void is a class in java. From Docs

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a
>   reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.

Comment: My eclipse saying This method must return a result of type Void